# Binding complex types without overriding ToString

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, model-binding

I am using a custom model binder to bind my complex type.

Here's the model:

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(SupplierModelBinder))]
public class SupplierModel
{
    public string VendorId { get; set; }

    public string VendorName { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return VendorId;
    }
}
```

Here's the binder:

```
public class SupplierModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        string key = bindingContext.ModelName;
        ValueProviderResult val = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key);
        if (val != null)
        {
            string s = val.AttemptedValue as string;
            if (s != null)
            {
                return new SupplierModel() { VendorId = s };
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm rendering the model using `Html.ActionLink` calls the `UserModel`'s `ToString` method. When that `GET`s to the server it uses the result of that to bind the model.

This works great (I'm not bothered about the `VendorName` property here), however it does rely on overriding `ToString` in the model class so I can use that value in the model binder.

How can I separate the binding/unbinding of my complex type from the `ToString` method?

I don't want to have to override `ToString` just so my model gets rendered correctly for my binder to interpret. For other types I'll have to (de)serialise to JSON or simiar, which I don't want to be in `ToString`.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you're trying to do here? In particular, why do you need a custom model binder for this class at all?

Comment: This class is a property of a model I'm trying to submit in a clickable link (get request) to the server. With no binding it says no type converter exists between string and SupplierModel. I think it's because it's a get request is not so simple. I'm using html.actionlink to create the link so can't construct the exact url/querystring manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to figure out how to do this without using a custom binding. The trick is realising that if I have things like `Supplier.VendorId="XXXX"` as part of the query string of the action link that gets rendered then it gets mapped correctly.

I used reflection to see what `HtmlHelper.ActionLink()` does when it's passed an object, which is that it creates an instance of `RouteValueDictionary<string, object>`, which creates a key for each property of the object.

This default implementation is close to what I want, but I need it to deal with properties of properties.

Luckly there's an overload of `ActionLink()` that takes a `RouteValueDictionary<string, object>` directly, so that left me with the problem of constructing one with the `Property.SubProperty` type keys correctly.

I ended up with the code below, which firstly uses the `RouteValueDictonary`'s constructor to get a key for each property.
Then it removes any that won't get bound according to the `Bind` attribute (if the class has one), which tidies up the resulting querystring quite a bit.

The main part it does though is to look for any properties of type `...Model` (the type name ending with "Model") and add that object's properties to the dictionary. I needed to use some rule for whether to recurse or not otherwise it would try and walk the properties of things like lists of objects etc. I figure that I'm already using a convention for my model classes, so I could stick to it.

---

```
public static RouteValueDictionary ToRouteValueDictionary(this object obj)
{
    var Result = new RouteValueDictionary(obj);

    // Find any ignored properties
    var BindAttribute = (BindAttribute)obj.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(BindAttribute), true).SingleOrDefault();

    var ExcludedProperties = new List<string>();

    if (BindAttribute != null)
    {
        ExcludedProperties.AddRange(BindAttribute.Exclude.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
    }

    // Remove any ignored properties from the dictionary
    foreach (var ExcludedProperty in ExcludedProperties)
    {
        Result.Remove(ExcludedProperty);
    }

    // Loop through each property, recursively adding sub-properties that end with "Model" to the dictionary
    foreach (var Property in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (ExcludedProperties.Contains(Property.Name))
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (Property.PropertyType.Name.EndsWith("Model"))
        {
            Result.Remove(Property.Name);

            var PropertyValue = Property.GetValue(obj, null);

            if (PropertyValue != null)
            {
                var PropertyDictionary = PropertyValue.ToRouteValueDictionary();

                foreach (var Key in PropertyDictionary.Keys)
                {
                    Result.Add(string.Format("{0}.{1}", Property.Name, Key), PropertyDictionary[Key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return Result;
}
```